# Output format of python code in csv file

Tags: python, csv

I have the following python code. It is supposed to print the output in table type format into a csv file e.g.

```
A  B  C  D  E  F  G  H  I  J
2  4  5  7  9  7  6  5  4  2
.
.
.
```

But the output is printing one value per line

```
A
B
C
.
.
.
2
3
4
.
.
```

Here is the code

```
import random
import csv

with open('table.csv', 'w') as file:
    csv_write = csv.writer(file,delimiter='\t')


    for i in range(ord('A'), ord('J')+1):
        row = [chr(i)]
        csv_write.writerow(row)

    for j in range(1,11):
        for k in range(1,1001):
            row2 = [random.randint(1,10001)]
            csv_write.writerow(row2)
```

Comment: writerow takes entire list that needs to be written in a single line. So you have to pass a list with ['A', 'B', ..., 'I', 'J'] to writerow. Currently you are passing ['A'] to writerow and then ['B'] and so on. Make these changes and your code will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import random
import csv

with open('table.csv', 'w', newline='') as file:
    csv_write = csv.writer(file,delimiter='\t')
    header = [ chr(i) for i in range(ord('A'), ord('J')+1)]
    csv_write.writerow(header)

    for k in range(1,1001):
        row = random.sample(range(1,10001), 10)
        csv_write.writerow(row)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this works but there is no space (tab) between the values. The answers are in the format ABCDEFGHIJ

Comment: I guess you have tried opening the file in excel. If you try it to open in notepad ++ you will see the tabs, or you might split the cols in excel based on tabs to see separate columns

Comment: I agree with @Rao, the tabs are present in the file

Answer (score 0):

Make list outer loop.`

```
import random
import csv

with open('table.csv', 'w') as file:
    csv_write = csv.writer(file, delimiter=',')
    col = []
    row2 = []

    for i in range(ord('A'), ord('J')+1):
        col.append(chr(i))
    csv_write.writerow(col)

    for j in range(1):
        for k in range(1,11):
            row2.append(random.randint(1,10))            
    csv_write.writerow(row2)
```

`